# Stylize the select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css

I'm trying to stylize my related select drop down like this in the below screenshot, but I can't work out how.

[image]

Please could  someone have any clue how this website did it?

Comment: Please provide us with what you've tried.

Comment: share that site  link please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` tags aren't easily customizable with CSS. Therefore, we usually need to hide the original `select` and create a new element that will be customized with CSS and JS.

For example, given the following `select`:

```
<select class="Dropdown">
    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="3">Category 3</option>
    <option value="4">Category 4</option>
    <option value="5">Category 5</option>
    <option value="6">Category 6</option>
    <option value="7">Category 7</option>
    <option value="8">Category 8</option>
    <option value="9">Category 9</option>
    <option value="10">Category 10</option>
</select>
```

First, we hide the original `select`:

```
var dropdown = $('.Dropdown').hide();
```

Then, we create a new `div` element, and append it to our page:

```
var newDropdown = $('<div/>') // create new div element
    .addClass('NewDropdown') // with class NewDropdown
    .appendTo(document.body); // and append it to page
```

For each `option` in our original `select`, we create an element inside our new dropdown.

```
dropdown.find('option').each(function(index, element){
    var option = $(element); // this is the option from the original select
    var newOption = $('<div/>') // create new div element
        .addClass('NewDropdown-item') // with class NewDropdown-item
        .html(option.html()) // copy content from original option
        .data('value', option.val()) // copy value from original option
        .on('click', onClicked) // add a click listener
        .appendTo(newDropdown); // append it to the new dropdown
});
```

For convenience, we will store the newly created dropdown items in a variable:

```
var newDropdownOptions = newDropdown.find('.NewDropdown-item');
```

When one of the items in the new dropdown is clicked, we mark it as selected and set the original `select`'s value.

```
function onClicked(){
    newDropdownOptions.removeClass('is-selected'); // deselect all items
    var clickedOption = $(this); // wrap clicked option in jquery
    clickedOption.addClass('is-selected'); // add class to mark clicked option as selected
    dropdown.val(clickedOption.data('value')); // set original select's value
};
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhrmcouz/

Comment: that's it! thank you very much Eduardo!

Obrigado :)